# Inno Setup - "New Folder" is automatically added to a selected destination folder

Tags: inno-setup

I want to install/extract all files into the folder I chose from the Setup Wizard. However I don't get to it, because there is always a sub directory created.

For example, if I choose: `C:\MyFolder`, the installer automatically adds `New Folder` to it.

How do I install without any auto made sub directory?

My code:

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={sd}\
DisableDirPage=no
```

And here an example:

[image]

I chose Directory: `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\123`

However it selects the directory:
`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\123\New Folder`

I don't want to use the `New folder` but simply use the chosen `123` folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Inno Setup tries to preserve the last component of the path, if you choose another target path.

So if the default path (`DefaultDirName`) is like `C:\Program Files\My Program` and you choose `D:\Programs`, it will automatically append the `My Program` to become `D:\Programs\My Program`.

In your case, the Inno Setup is confused by the default path lacking any subfolder. And it (not really correctly) appends the `New folder` instead. Are you sure you really want to install to `C:\` root?

Anyway, if that's intentional, set the `AppendDefaultDirName` to `no`.

See the [documentation on the `AppendDefaultDirName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appenddefaultdirname):

> By default, when a folder in the dialog displayed by the *Browse...* button on the *Select Destination Location* wizard page is clicked, Setup automatically appends the last component of `DefaultDirName` onto the new path. For example, if `DefaultDirName` is `{pf}\My Program` and "Z:\" is clicked, the new path will become "Z:\My Program".
>
> Setting this directive to `no` disables the aforementioned behavior. In addition, it causes a *Make New Folder* button to appear on the dialog.

Comment: Thanks, was the solution i was looking for!